# SSRS - Sum value and porcent

Tags: reporting-services, sum

I have a problem in my Report

I have a table like this:

```
Description | Mounth

[Description] | [Sum(Valeur)]

Porcent
```

When I execute this I have

```
Descr M1 M2 M3 M4 M5 M6 M7 M8 M9 M10

Desc1 X1 X2 X3 X4 X5 X6 X7 X8 X9 X10

Desc2 Y1 Y2 Y3 Y4 Y5 Y6 Y7 Y8 Y9 Y10

%%%%  P1 P2 P3 P4 P5 P6 P7 P8 P9 P10
```

In the Porcent row I need to have the porcent of `Desc1` value / `Desc2` value

example:  `p1 = Y1 / X1`

`p2 = Y2 / X2 ...`

How can I do this just in 1 expression in the textbox `Porcent` of my table?

Thanks for your help

Comment: Are you using a column grouping for the sequential values?

Answer (score 0):

do you know how to use **reportIteams**???
If yes the do one thing create two small single cell tables. and assign the Desc1 field to one  table and Desc2  to another table.
now in the table field where you want to show p1 = Y1 / X1 write below code.
=ReportItems!tablix1 (which has value of Desc2) / ReportItems!tablix1 (which has value of Desc1)

it will work for sure.
but still if you face any issue let me know. you can mail me on **dilipc01@gmail.com**
and remember you have used two single cell tables, make size of tables very very small, make font size to 1 and color to white so it will be not visible in Report, **do not try to hide your two small tables else ReportItems Property will not work**.
if you want more help please leave a comment will help you.

Regards,
Dilip Chauhan.